# Not getting the same number of results in my test run

Tags: jmeter

In the same Jmeter tests, I'm getting different line of results in the csv.
In one I'm getting ~80 in the others I'm getting ~800.
Is there a setting, that I'm always getting the same numbers of results in the .csv?

I'm also using slaves, so this should just scale up, with one slave it should be 80 and with 10 slaves it should be 800?

Everything is in a big CI/CD pipeline. So I tried multiple runs.
But never got the same line of results for the same test.

Here is my jmx xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.3">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Testplan OneHundred" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="ThreadGroup1" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">stoptestnow</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">100</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">100</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="GetRequest" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="Variables pré-définies" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">80</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Host</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">fend</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
            <objProp>
              <name>saveConfig</name>
              <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                <time>true</time>
                <latency>true</latency>
                <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                <success>true</success>
                <label>true</label>
                <code>true</code>
                <message>true</message>
                <threadName>true</threadName>
                <dataType>true</dataType>
                <encoding>false</encoding>
                <assertions>true</assertions>
                <subresults>true</subresults>
                <responseData>false</responseData>
                <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                <xml>false</xml>
                <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                <bytes>true</bytes>
                <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                <url>true</url>
                <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                <connectTime>true</connectTime>
              </value>
            </objProp>
            <stringProp name="filename">/masterdata/results/auth/cb/response_eight_get.csv</stringProp>
          </ResultCollector>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

This is the message I got inside the terminal:

```
aiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.2/s Avg:   771 Min:   771 Max:   771 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 80 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary +    104 in 00:00:21 =    4.9/s Avg:  9733 Min:    10 Max: 21163 Err:    80 (76.92%) Active: 0 Started: 30 Finished: 80
summary =    105 in 00:00:22 =    4.7/s Avg:  9647 Min:    10 Max: 21163 Err:    80 (76.19%)
Tidying up remote @ Tue Oct 27 22:08:54 UTC 2020 (1603836534920)
... end of run
```

And the last few entries in the results.csv

```
1603836484132,15040,GetRequest,Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: Socket closed,ThreadGroup1 1-9,text,false,,2682,0,4,4,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard/,0,0,185
1603836484168,14999,GetRequest,Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: Socket closed,ThreadGroup1 1-1,text,false,,2682,0,4,4,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard/,0,0,154
1603836484179,14998,GetRequest,Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: Socket closed,ThreadGroup1 1-4,text,false,,2682,0,4,4,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard/,0,0,137
```

Comment: Did your test stopped or error ? (you marked `on_sample_error">stoptestnow`)

Comment: Edit:
I added more information to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have 10 users and 100 loops in your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) hence you should get 1000 total results (if everything goes well)
2. At the same time you have `Stop Test Now` after a Sampler error, it means that your test will stop **immediately** (and not gracefully) whenever even a single request fails

   [image]
3. All JMeter slaves are executing the same test plan **absolutely independenly** so for 1 slave you will have 1000 results, for 2 slaves - 2000, for 8 slaves - 8000, etc. but again only if everything will be ok, any single failure will cause your test to immediately stop forcefully terminating the connections (and adding more errors) so you might want to switch this "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" to `Continue` and it will allow you to have equal amount of results each time you run your test.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)